# Does a bat file know its name and can it delete itself

Tags: windows, batch-file

At some point in my script, I'd like the bat script to delete itself. This requires that the script know its name and then to use that name to delete itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

None of the existing answers provide a clean way for a batch file to delete itself and exit without any visible error message.

Simply including `del "%~f0"` does delete the script, but it also results in an ugly *"The batch file cannot be found."* error message.

If it is OK for the script to close the parent CMD process (the console window), then the following works fine without any error message:

```
del "%~f0"&exit
```

But it is a bit more complicated if you want the script to delete itself and exit *without* closing the parent CMD process, and without any error message.

Method 1: Start a second process that runs within the same console window that actually performs the delete. The `EXIT /B` is probably not necessary, but I put it in to maximize the probability that the batch script will close before the STARTed process attempts to delete the file.

```
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

Method 2: Create and transfer control to another temp batch file that deletes itself as well as the caller, but don't use CALL, and redirect stderr to nul.

```
>"%~f0.bat" echo del "%~f0" "%~f0.bat"
2>nul "%~f0.bat"
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, %0 will be the path used to call the batch file.

Comment: I'm curious, what happens when a Batch File (or any program for that matter) calls another batch file...what `%0` in the Second batch file?

Comment: I'd have to try that, but my guess would be that it's the path provided in the caller batch file.

Comment: No, it is the current batch file.

Comment: So, to be sure I understand, if A.bat calls B.bat, %0 is "B.bat", right? That was my guess, though I may have not stated it clearly.

Comment: %0 is always the call of the current batch file.

Comment: `%~0` might also be the name of a called subroutine, depending on where it appears. But `"%~f0"` will always be the full path to the script, even if within subroutine or after CD or PUSHD.

Answer (score 2):

Tested and working:

```
del %0
exit
```

Comment: It may be better done this way:  `del "%~f0" & exit /b`. "%~f0" takes care of running batch file from different directory, and of spaces in the path. Putting both commands on a single line avoids possible "file not found" error which may happen sometimes in the original form, if the line containing `exit` is not buffered before `del` is executed. Finally, `/b` exits just the batch file, instead of closing the entire console.

Comment: @atzz - but `exit /b` instead of `exit` results in an ugly "The batch file cannot be found." error message.

Comment: @dbenham - You are correct. (Interestingly, I don't remember getting this message before; did cmd behavior change in the intervening years? Or is it my memory?) But in my book, it's much better than closing the console outright.

Comment: @atzz - agreed :-)  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17006630/1012053) for methods to delete cleanly without error message.

Answer (score 1):

%0 gives you the relative path the from the directory where the bat file was started. So if you call it

```
mybats\delyourself.bat tango roger
```

%0 will contain `mybats\delyourself.bat`

`del %0` works if you haven't changed your current directory.

`%~f0` exapnds to the full path to the file.

Comment: There is no need for `SET path_to_bat=%~f0` since `%~f0` will ***always*** give the full path to the currently running batch script, even if used within called subroutine or if CD or PUSHD has been executed since start.

Comment: d'oh of course! fixed it, don't know why I thought it would be needed. I've updated the reply.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was important, that I have **no** errorLevel 1 after I exited the batch file. I found an suitable and easy answer this way:
**DeleteMyself.cmd:**

```
START CMD /C DEL DeleteMyself.cmd
```

Test batch if DeleteMyself.cmd is returning errorLevel 0. **TestDeleteMyself.cmd**:

```
call DeleteMyself.cmd
echo Errorlevel: %errorLevel%
```