# Deleting an Exe Batch Script itself

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have compiled my batch (.bat) file into exe, lets name it Run.exe, I want to tell it to delete itself at the end of its work. How can I do this through commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a bat file know its name and can it delete itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849095/does-a-bat-file-know-its-name-and-can-it-delete-itself)

Comment: no not the same because here we have an exe file which copy batch script into temp folder, if I use %0 then it will delete the batch file in temp folder not the real exe which is running

Comment: How did you converted your bat? Why the `%0` will give you a path to different file?

Comment: You could use WMI's `Win32_Process.ExecutablePath` to track down the run.exe and find it's path.  Then a `del` command to delete it.

Comment: Why "Del /*./*" is not working?  (read it without "/")

Comment: did you try to make possible to transmit your exe path as parameter to bat file ? Maybe this ca be a workaround?

Comment: I have found a solution, I must terminate the exe file then use the Del /*./* command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the end of your script:

```
( del /q /f "%~f0" >nul 2>&1 & exit /b 0  )
```

This will tell it to exit and delete its self and i have tested it when compiled to an exe so it works. This can be a bit unreliable so you could try this also

```
call :end&exit /b
:end
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

Try both and see witch one works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

`taskkill /im ME.exe /f && cd /d %~dp0 && del /f /q ME.exe`

This will have the exe that is compiled from a BatchFile delete itself.
replace ME.exe with the name of the compiled executable.